# How to merge an additional remote branch (not origin) into local branch?

Tags: git

I've added an additional remote to by git repository with:
`git remote add template git@bitbucket.org:example/template.git`

Output of `git remote -v`:

```
origin  git@bitbucket.org:example/project-subs.git (fetch)
origin  git@bitbucket.org:example/project-subs.git (push)
template    git@bitbucket.org:example/template.git (fetch)
template    git@bitbucket.org:example/template.git (push)
```

Output of `git branch -a`:

```
* master
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  remotes/origin/master
  remotes/template/master
```

How can I now merge / pull `remotes/template/master` into my local branch `master`?

Comment: `git pull template master` should do the job. You didn't write you have tired this and if you did and it didn't work  what is the error.

Comment: @MarekR branch/name? What does name refer to?

Comment: I've corrected pervious comment.

Comment: That works for me. Happy to accept if posted as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution as posted by  Marek R

```
git pull template master
```

Comment: `git checkout -b` creates a *local* branch (not that "local branch" is a well-defined thing, but the adjective serves to distinguish it from a *remote-tracking branch name* which is not actually a branch. By creating a local branch whose name resembles that of a remote-tracking branch, you've just made things difficult for yourself, as if you were to call your brother "Cousin Bob" when you actually *have* a cousin named Bob. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Checkout your local `master`, then `git merge template/master`

Comment: git merge template/master
merge: template/master - not something we can merge